# add text at the end of specific line

Tags: awk, text, sed

I have a yaml file like this:

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3
```

I'm finding adding this text:  `# {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }` at the end of the line containing the word `image` surprisingly hard.

I've tried with `sed`, `awk` and `ruby` but I can't get it straight, sed is especially confusing with all those special characters and spaces.

the end result should be this:

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3 # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }
```

thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\s*image:.*/&  # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }/' file
```

Match a line that following some whitespace begins `image:` and append  `# {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }/` to it.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
sed '/image/s/$/ # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }/' file.yaml
```

The address `/image/` matches a line containing the word `image`. The regexp `$` matches the end of the line, and this is replaced with the string you want to add, in order to append to the line.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let file.txt content be

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3
```

then

```
awk '{print $0 (/image/?" # {\"$imagepolicy\": \"xxx:xxx-test-pr333\" }":"")}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3 # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }
```

Explanation: I used so-called ternary operator (*condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse*) so if current line do contain `/image/` I `print` concatenation of current line (`$0`) and given string otherwise concatenation of current line with empty string (`""`) that is unchange line. Note that `"` (and only `"`) needs to be escaped (`\`) as they used for delimiting strings in GNU `AWK`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

`awk` one-liner solution - tested and confirmed working on `mawk 1.3.4`, `gawk 5.1.1`, and `macos nawk`.

No matter how many times `"image"` shows up within one line, `OFS` (now set to the desired padding text) would only be appended **once**. And since `FS` is the full line `^$`, lines could only have `NF` value of `0` (zero byte line) or `1` (everything else), so none of the existing spaces and tabs would get distorted.

- *One extra bonus is that the way it's written, it could even be used in* `gawk`*-unicode mode to safely append text to "lines" within purely binary files (add `RT` check for files not ending with `\n`), if there's ever such a need.*

**INPUT**

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3
```

**CODE**

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF+=/image/' FS='^$' OFS=' # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3 # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ str='# {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333"}'
$ awk -F"\t" -v s="$str" '/^[ ]+image:/{$++NF=s}1' input_file 
spec:
  values:
    image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:mypr-ij4uhtuh3 # {"$imagepolicy": "xxx:xxx-test-pr333"}
```

Match `image:` then add new column `$++NF=s`.

The content of `s` is `$str` declared with `-v s="$str"`